# This is a good way to organize the classes from the service layer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, directory-structure, service-layer

Currently I have the following structure:

```
Model/
    Entities/
    Repositories/
    Proxies/
    Services/
        User/
            Manager.php
            Relations/
                 Friendship.php
        Group/
            Manager.php
            Administration.php
            Posts/
                Manager.php
        ...
```

Since I'm using Doctrine, I have chosen this structure because each folder corresponds to one entity. Are there any problems in organizing this way?

I would like to know your opinion on how to avoid changes to the folders' structure in the future caused by bad organization now. Is there a better way to organize the classes from the service layer? What can you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a perfect valid structures, however, I may have two recommendations :

- I usually put my proxies outside of my library folder, because first, it is a special class which doesn't follow the `PSR-0` recommendation, and second, you may need to remove those class when doing database update, for those reasons, I put them in `/var/tmp/proxies`
- The service layer structure looks ok, but be sure to apply to your logic and not to your entities, I mean, a UserService is perfectly valid to gather all logic behind a user, but may also be used with some other entities because of their relationship. Conclusion "One Entity !== One Service"
- I also avoid Plural form, that's a bit personnal point, but it is a bit similar to the naming convention used in Database System, a table represent a entity and therefore shouldn't accept plural forms. By the way, most of the framework (ie. Zf/Symfony2/Doctrine2) use singular.
- Last but least, whatever structure you choose now, be consistent, we'll never tell it enough, I sometimes take projects back from other people, and even I don't understand why or how they did it like this, I try to follow their conventions, when working on a project with a team, it is a *requirement*.

If you decide one day to refactor your structure, take a day or two, and do it every where, or don't.

Comment: Thanks Guéry, I'm using singular names in the persistence (db) and entities, the folders in the plural there was only a little carelessness of mine. Thanks for the touch on the proxies, really the best thing to do is put them in a temporary folder, since they are generated by Doctrine. A class of service will not necessarily be related to an entity, one example is the class of service for a User may have a method for acl, but this method will only serve as proxies to another class of service responsible for the ACL, this is a good practice, right?

Comment: Well I think it really depends on your application, however, I never put any Authorization Logic in my UserService. Think about Unit Testing, what if you need to use your UserService, you'll have to mock a logged user, or write your service accordingly to your test, that's not a good ideas. I most of the time use a AuthorizationService which is in charge to check for permissions, with an isAllowed() method (such as Zend_Acl).

Comment: It requires a bit more code for each Service calls but it is much more flexible ihmo, you keep your Acl free of any resource, role, privilege. When you need to change a permission, you just have to edit your AuthorizationService or any related configuration files.